# UIView Animation does not actually set new values?

Tags: ios, animation, uiview, resize, position

I'm having a problem with UI animations.

I have a uiview: theView.

I animate theView to move to some random position on the mainView. It moves from point A to point B and changes its scale from 1.0 to 1.5;
So after the animation, the view is bigger and in a new position.

I call a second animation, by button. This one only move theView. 
After the animation, the view has moved. However, the view is no longer bigger, its scale is back at 1.0.

So do these animation values not become theViews new values for size,position,ex?

I will post code soon, because it of course may be a careless error I am missing.

Comment: How are you animating your view? CAAnimation or UIView animation?

Answer (score 0):

I cannot post a comment, so I would just like to suggest that you say `UIView`, i'm not 100% sure, so dont take my word for it, but im pretty sure you should use `UIImageView` instead. Hope that helps a little :)

```
// create the view that will execute our animation
 UIImageView* campFireView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:self.view.frame];

 // load all the frames of our animation
 campFireView.animationImages = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:    
                             [UIImage imageNamed:@"campFire01.gif"],
                             [UIImage imageNamed:@"campFire02.gif"],
                             [UIImage imageNamed:@"campFire03.gif"],
                             [UIImage imageNamed:@"campFire04.gif"],
                             [UIImage imageNamed:@"campFire05.gif"],
                             [UIImage imageNamed:@"campFire06.gif"],
                             [UIImage imageNamed:@"campFire07.gif"],
                             [UIImage imageNamed:@"campFire08.gif"],
                             [UIImage imageNamed:@"campFire09.gif"],
                             [UIImage imageNamed:@"campFire10.gif"],
                             [UIImage imageNamed:@"campFire11.gif"],
                             [UIImage imageNamed:@"campFire12.gif"],
                             [UIImage imageNamed:@"campFire13.gif"],
                             [UIImage imageNamed:@"campFire14.gif"],
                             [UIImage imageNamed:@"campFire15.gif"],
                             [UIImage imageNamed:@"campFire16.gif"],
                             [UIImage imageNamed:@"campFire17.gif"], nil];

 // all frames will execute in 1.75 seconds
 campFireView.animationDuration = 1.75;
 // repeat the annimation forever
 campFireView.animationRepeatCount = 0;
 // start animating
 [campFireView startAnimating];
 // add the animation view to the main window 
 [self.view addSubview:campFireView];
```

Comment: @DTDev Yes, sir. You play the animation via a series of images. See my original answer with some sample code :)

Answer (score 0):

If its UIView animation.

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

        _yourView = [[UIView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(300, 300, 100, 100)];
        [_yourView setBackgroundColor:[UIColor redColor]];
        [self.view addSubview:_yourView];

        [UIView animateWithDuration:1.0f animations:^{
        [_yourView setFrame:CGRectMake(400, 400, 150, 150)];
        } completion:nil];

        UIButton *aMoveButton = [[UIButton alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(10.0f, 5.0f, 60.0f, 40.0f)];
        [aMoveButton setTitle:@"MoveView" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
        [aMoveButton addTarget:self action:@selector(moveYourView) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchDown];
        [self.view addSubview:aMoveButton];
```

}

```
-(void)moveYourView{
    [UIView animateWithDuration:1.0f animations:^{
        [_yourView setFrame:CGRectMake(300, 500, 150, 150)];
    } completion:nil];
}
```

Believe me this works and it actually changes the view's values for size,position.

Comment: You are right when you set the Frame. For some reason, the behavior with TransformScale was different.